# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). How to solve this issue?

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

I am running Magento 2.3 with NGINX, PHP7.1 and MariaDb.
This is a fresh instalation with pre-loaded data.
I am getting these follow error:

```
$ tail var/log/system.log
[2019-01-09 16:36:24] main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
[2019-01-09 16:36:24] main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
[2019-01-09 16:36:24] main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
[2019-01-09 17:33:08] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-01-09 17:33:08] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-01-09 17:33:09] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-01-09 17:33:10] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-01-09 17:33:11] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-01-09 17:33:11] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-01-09 17:33:36] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 3334; Allocated memory size: 40008000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
```

And these are screenshots:
[image]

[image]

How can I solve these errors?
Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried deploying static content and giving proper permissions?

Comment: yes. I have used `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`  and chmod 777. After that the page gets a infinite loop with javascript until the server is crashed.

Comment: did you resolve the issue/

Answer (score 1):

Please try to give permission as follow

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;               // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;               // 755 permission for directory 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;           // 777 permission for var folder    
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **run** the following **`commands`** :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

check if it resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

try remove folder:

```
rm -rf generated/ 
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ 
rm -rf var/cache/
rm -rf var/view_processed
```

after that, run command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```